# Unable to Authorize Or Get Token

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, guzzle, laravel-passport

I am having trouble getting a laravel application to access an api endpoint in another laravel app, same server. I can get it to work in terminal, and postman but not from the laravel app itself, both getting an auth token and using work in p;ostman and terminal but not in laravel. (killing me that this was working the other day)

I have tried many Guzzle and curl configs, Using WAMP on Win 10. Laravel Framework version 5.3.31,  PHP 7.2.18

```
try {
            $response = $http->request('POST',$this->base_oauth_url. 'oauth/token', [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                ],
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => self::API_CLIENT_ID,
                    'client_secret' => self::API_SECRET,
                    'username' => self::API_USERNAME,
                    'password' => self::API_PASSWORD,
                    'scope' => '*',
                ],
                'debug'=>$this->debug,
                'allow_redirects' => false,
                'verify' => false,

            ]);

        } catch (ClientException $e) {
            throw new Exception("Guzzle Error: {$e->getMessage()}");

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception("Send Error: ({$e->getCode()}): {$e->getMessage()}");
        }

        $response = json_decode((string) $response->getBody()->getContents());
        $data = array();
        $data['access_token'] = $response->access_token;
        $data['refresh_token'] = $response->refresh_token;
```

Error: 
Guzzle Error: Client error: `POST http://mytestdomain.com/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}

Comment: Is this helpful https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/221#issuecomment-269828055? Looks like some database mismatch